# Can Apache Commons CLI parse new args on the fly?

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

So I have a Java test that will have different parameters that are named by the user so I don't know the "-parm " until run time. There are standard args that I have added to my test and this is working fine but is there a way to basically parse the arg list from the command line and when it hits a parm it doesn't recognize it adds it to the list on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

How will your code know what to do with these args if it has no clue about them before run-time?

Comment: Its a bit complicated.. we have a GUI that users can create a test case, they can define these custom parms and then use them in the steps of their test. This test is saved as a XML file. We have driver code that translates this and basically saves a big list of the parms and uses them when they are needed. The driver is in C and we are now working on a big project to move it to Java and I'm looking into this area.